# Shortening large chunks of code

Tags: code-optimization

Some of the code that I have is unbearably long and drives me insane. I don't know if there were simpler ways to doing what I am doing.

```
long turn1;
long turn2;
long turn3;
long turn4;
long turn5;
long turn6;
long turn7; 
long turn8;
long turn9;
long turn10;
long turn11;
long turn12;
long turn13;
long turn14;
long turn15;
```

#################

```
  turn1 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn2 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn3 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn4 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn5 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn6 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn7 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn8 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn9 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn10 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn11 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn12 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn13 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn14 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
  turn15 = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
```

#

```
if (turn1 == turn2 or turn2 == turn3 or turn3 == turn4 or turn4 == turn5 or turn6 == turn7 or turn7 == turn8 or turn8 == turn9 or turn9 == turn10 or turn10 == turn11 or turn11 == turn12 or turn12 == turn13 or turn13 == turn14 or turn14 == turn15) {
```

#

```
lcd.print(turns[turn1]);
lcd.print(turns[turn2]);
lcd.print(turns[turn3]);
lcd.print(turns[turn4]);
lcd.print(turns[turn5]);
lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
lcd.print(turns[turn6]);
lcd.print(turns[turn7]);
lcd.print(turns[turn8]);
lcd.print(turns[turn9]);
lcd.print(turns[turn10]);
lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
lcd.print(turns[turn11]);
lcd.print(turns[turn12]);
lcd.print(turns[turn13]);
lcd.print(turns[turn14]);
lcd.print(turns[turn15]);
```

Comment: You mean like using an array and loops?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, and the solution is very simple. It's in two parts, and they make up part of the absolute fundamental building blocks not just in C, but in almost any programming language.

You can read good information on arrays [**here**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), and 'for loops' [**here**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) (it's about half way down the page). Without wishing to offend, it seems like you are missing some really basic concepts and I recommend starting at the beginning of the [**tutorial series**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) that the two aforementioned links are part of.

I'll just cover the basics. If you don't understand anything, refer to the tutorials. If you *still* don't understand then please comment, but make sure you can convince us that you've really given it a good go. We're here to help as long as you're here to learn.

To declare an array of *N* variables, all of which are the same type, you use:

```
<type> <name_of_variable> [<number_of_elements>];

or:

long turns[15];
```

Now you have an array of 15 `long`s. Ta da!

You now have to set the values of each turn. As your values are all the same (if you ignore the fact that `random()` ultimately leaves you with different values) you can use a **for loop**:

```
for (int x=0; x<15; x++)
{
    turns[x] = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
}
```

I won't explain how a for loop works; I gave you a link to the tutorial to save me writing it all out myself.

That covers shrinking of part 1 and 2. Part 3 requires a little more thought. That said, as you didn't complete your *if* statement, I don't actually know what you plan to do if any two adjacent `turn` elements are the same. I shall assume that you would 're-randomise' one of the duplicates. For this you can again use a for loop, starting at the beginning and running to *N-1* th element, where *N* is the total number of elements:

```
for (int x=0; x<14; x++)
{
    if (turns[x] == turns[x+1])
    {
        turns[x+1] = random(sizeof(turns) / sizeof(char*));
    }
}
```

You need make sure that `turns[x+1]` is not outside of the array, which is why the for loop runs for one iteration less than there are elements.

The fourth shrinkable part is just a matter of swtiching multiple print statements into single for loops:

```
for (int x=0; x<NUMBER_OF_PRINTS_IN_1st_BUNCH; x++)
    lcd.print(turns[x]);
lcd.setcursor(0,2);
for (int x=WHERE_YOU_LEFT_OFF; x<NUMBER_OF_PRINTS_IN_2nd_BUNCH; x++)
    lcd.print(turns[x]);
lcd.setcursor(0,3);
for (int x=WHERE_YOU_LEFT_OFF_AGAIN; x<NUMBER_OF_REMAINING_PRINTS; x++)
    lcd.print(turns[x]);
```

All done.

Comment: Is it my imagination or are you off-by-one, @chaaarlie2? Your array is of length 15, so is 0-14; in the first for loop code, you say `int x=0; x<16; x++` - surely that will go around from 0 to 15, not 0 to 14? Same applies to the second for loop (reduced by 1 to skip the last value).

Comment: Alternative to the fourth part: do one loop to do all of them, then `if (x==4) lcd.setcursor(0,2); if (x==9) lcd.setcursor(0,3);`

Comment: @AMADANON it's obviously my imagination, not yours. I wrote the whole answer with reference to 16 values, then when I noticed the OP didn't have "long turn0;" at the start, went back and only remembered to change the first two references. Answer updated, thanks for spotting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, for the third shrinkable, good assumption, that's actually what I am doing. On another note, is there a way to fix if two of them match? The turn values are stated as this: {"L2 ", "R2 ", "F2 ", "U2 ", "D2 ", "B2 " , "L' ", "R' ", "F' ", "U' ", "D' ", "B' ", "L ", "R ", "U ", "F ", "D ", "B "} , is there a way I could prevent something like L2 L or L2 L'?

Comment: Also, turns[] was already declared in `char *turns[]`, so i end up getting `conflicting declaration 'long int turns [15]'` Heres the chunk: `char *turns[] = {"L2 ", "R2 ", "F2 ", "U2 ", "D2 ", "B2 " , "L' ", "R' ", "F' ", "U' ", "D' ", "B' ", "L ", "R ", "U ", "F ", "D ", "B "};
long turns[15];`

Comment: I assume `char *turns[] = {"L2 ", "R2 " ... };` is your list of possible values, and `long turns[15]` holds an array of 15 random values from your that list? I'm afraid you've got yourself in a muddle again. You can't have two variables with the same name, even if they're different types; you're attempting to declare two things called `turns`. No! Perhaps have `char *turnChoices[]` instead - always consider *naming your variables in a way that tells a stranger what the variable means*. This is definitely a good idea if you're new to programming, because it's easy to forget what does what!

Comment: Next up I have to complain about how you're doing what it looks like you're trying to do: **1.** Make a list of possible turn 'commands'; **2.** Make a list of *N* random choices from that list of possible commands. Nothing wrong with that idea, it's perfectly sensible, but you're going about it the wrong way. Really wrong! I understand that you're new to C, we all were once, so I **definitely** don't want to put you off when I keep referring you to tutorials; read [the section on *enumeration*](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) - it's exaclty what you need.